# WordPress : Get result from meta_query between tow number

Tags: wordpress

I  have value like :-

```
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-area'] ) ) {
        $f = $_GET['filter-area'];
        preg_match_all('!\d+!', $f, $matches);
        foreach($matches as $key) {
        $first_val = $key[0];
        $second_val = $key[1];
        }
    }
```

Now i need to search to get all date between this tow value.

So,, Itry this way, but its take one value.

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-area'] ) ) {
    $meta[] = array(
        'key'       => REALIA_PROPERTY_PREFIX . 'attributes_area',
        'value'     => $first_val,
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}
```

How can search by tow value

Comment: We need better explanation of what you try to achieve.. First of all, when checking parameters, use isset(). `if( isset($_GET['filter-area']) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According codex you can use

```
$args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
         'key'     => REALIA_PROPERTY_PREFIX . 'attributes_area',
         'value'   => array( $first_val, $second_val)
         'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
         'type'    => 'NUMERIC', 
       ),
    ),
);
```

OR this

```
 $args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
         'key'     => REALIA_PROPERTY_PREFIX . 'attributes_area',
         'value'   => $first_val
         'compare' => '>=',
         'type'    => 'NUMERIC', 
       ),
       array(
         'key'     => REALIA_PROPERTY_PREFIX . 'attributes_area',
         'value'   => $second_val
         'compare' => '<=',
         'type'    => 'NUMERIC', 
       ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)